# Connect to socket.io with ionic 3/angular 4 using dynamic connection url

Tags: angular, sockets, socket.io, ionic3

I'm creating an app with ionic3/angular4, where im connecting to a node-server.
This works fine, when the server ip/port is hardcoded in a config file. 
But I would like to change this approach, and fetch the server ip/port from a webservice instead.

I have used this guide, so my code looks like this example.
https://devdactic.com/ionic-realtime-socket-io/

Any advice how to adapt this to connect to a dynamic ip/port?

Comment: did you get any solution.

Comment: If you get any solution means plz share. When I try like ajax call in js file and include declare var socketurl; export let config: SocketIoConfig = { url: socketurl, options: {} }; this works in normal build. But not working in production build. Can any one help on this?